# How to create a XY chart in Java which reads data from two variables?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I have difficulties understanding how to add my data to the chart object. I am simulating a supermarket activity in java program. After the simulation time is up. I have two variables
 time and customers. What should I use if I want the data to be added to an XY chart in java.

Thanks, in advance. I have looked at JFreeChart but it seems overly complicated.

Comment: What do you need more than drawing on a JPanel?

Comment: More examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).

Answer (score 1):

JFreeChart is not overcomplicated. You have to try Time Series chart in your case. See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartTimeSeriesDemo8.htm) the example of how they use it.

Although they leave behind the scene the main thing, which should create the data source for chart: see line
 final TimeSeries eur = DemoDatasetFactory.createEURTimeSeries();

I used this TimeSeries charts before, and as I remember you have to create this object and put there series of your values (probably iterating over your own values and inserting them one by one in cycle)